# Trial cache partition not released after having uninstalled a package

Tags: platform-cache

Each time I uninstall a package from my scratch org, the trial cache capacity is not released. So the only possibility I have is to create a new scratch org, request a new trial cache and then install my new package.

How can I do to avoid creating a new scratch org ?

Thank you